# Proof using Markov's Inequality

Tags: probability

> Let $y$ denote a nonnegative random variable (continuous or discrete).
>   Assume that there is a $c\ge 0$ such that $E(y^n)\le c^n$ for every $n$.
>
> 1. Show that this implies: $P(y>c+ \varepsilon) = 0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. (Suggestion: Use Markov's inequality or a corresponding inequality).
> 2. Deduce that $P(y\le c) = 1$.

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: My bad, it should be y

Comment: Didn't you say that you were able to solve 1.? Why delete this mention?

Comment: I just realized that it may be wrong. I've commented below about it under Aduh's response.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y  > c$ iff $y > c +1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the increasing sequence of events $A_n:= \{y > c + 1/n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By continuity of probability, 
$$P(y>c) = P(\cup_nA_n) = \lim_nP(A_n)=0.$$
Now take the complement.

Comment: Why does it go to zero in the limit?

Comment: $P(A_n)=0$ for all $n$ by what you claim to have already showed.

Comment: Right, thanks for the help!

Comment: I proved the first statement by stating that $P(y>c+ \varepsilon)$ $\le$ $\frac{E(y-c)}{\varepsilon}$ by Markov's inequality, and then proceeding from there to the final conclusion. But I realize now that this probably isn't true for the discrete case. Could you offer any assistance as to a valid proof?

Comment: I was using this version: $P(x\ge a$) $\le$ $\frac{E(x)}{a}$. Now if I take x to be y-c and a to be $\varepsilon$, I can prove the LHS must equal to zero. But the question asks to prove the statement for $P(x>a)$. Does the inequality or the proof still hold in this case or is the whole thing invalid?

Comment: Can you prove that in general $P(x > a) \leq P(x \geq a)$?

Comment: Right, kind of funny that I was unconvinced now that you've pointed that out. Thanks!